# How to import data in IK

Tags: import, keyframes, inverse-kinematics

I've been using blender for a few months.

I made an IK (Inverse Kinematics) model and have 3D position data of hands.
What I've been doing was manually typing in the x, y, z coordinates in each frame and setting it as a keyframe. So when I had 10-second data in 10Hz, I had to put in 100 data points.

Is there any way to import the data of body points? (e.g., head, hands, pelvis, etc.)
As a graph, CSV file, or anything?

Thank you.

[image: IK model]